# How can I use "s" as a substitution delimiter in Perl?

Tags: perl

I was playing with Perl and thought that

```
sssssss
```

Would have been the same as

```
s/s/ss/
```

It seems only certain delimiters can be used. What are they?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use any non-whitespace character as the delimiter, but you can't use the delimiter inside *PATTERN* or *REPLACEMENT* without escaping it. This is totally valid:

```
my $x = 's';
$x =~ s s\ss\s\ss;
print $x; # prints "ss"
```

Note that a space is required after the first `s` or else it will be interpreted as `ss` identifier.